# How can I set the root folder for an Azure Websites site?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My folder structure is like so:

```
-build
 -unimportant stuff
-src
 -scripts
  -thirdParty
   -knockout
    -knockout.js
   -jquery
    -jquery.js
  -business
   -application.js
 -index.html
```

So, basically I have my entire site source inside a "src" folder, when I deploy that to Azure I have to change the default pages configuration to "src/index.html" which seems to work. My problem is that my scripts are not being loaded.

I have my scripts referenced like so:

In my local environment this works great, but it Azure it is not able to access the scripts. It seems that even though I am trying to use relative path, Azure is trying to access the scripts from it's root directory which is one level below where the scripts are.

Does anyone know how to change the Azure Website root directory to be set as my "src" directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution is to go to "Configure" in the management of your Azure Website. In the "app settings" section add a key of "Project" and a value in my case of "./src" then trigger a deployment. now only the directory you specified will be deployed and it will be deployed as the root.

Full instructions can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments